# google map api limit

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, client-side, server-side

I am running into the google map api call limit of 25.
Doing some research I came across this server side call, which people are referencing.
http://www.webstutorial.com/google-server-side-geocoding-php-infobox/website-tweaks/google

Now I don't understand the code, yet.
But my question is, why does it make a difference between calling the google map api's from php/server side and javascript/client side?

This might be a dumb question.  But just wondering.

thank you

Comment: AFAIK google tracks the requests by the IP address they come from. If you do this from the server, it will rack up those hits pretty quickly. From the client side, each client will have 25 hits to use.

Comment: Your link makes it pretty clear - there's a limit of 20 calls per client, and a limit of 2500 calls per server. If you've got 10,000 users, would you rather all 10,000 can make 20 calls each, or you only allow 2500 users to make one call through your server?

Comment: Maybe this is dumb but,
Does google then check the server request for php tag?  Then assume you are on a server?  Is that what they are doing?